# Определение значение переменной (новичок)

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $m=0;
    $n=0;
    $m=$m-1;
    $n=$m+1;
    if (($m+$n)< -3) {
        echo $n;
    }
?>
```

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста.
**Код должен был вывести -2,
Но уходит в false**

Comment: Ну смотрите у вас перед сравнением  `m = -1`, а `n=0`
Соответственно `m+n`  равно `-1`
`-1 > -3` что есть false.
`$n=0` в булевом типе `0==false`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $m=0;
    $n=0;
    $m=$m-1;  // m = -1, n = 0
    $n=$m+1;  // m = -1, n = 0
    if (($m+$n)< -3) { // -1 < -3 => false
        echo $n;
    }
?>
```